# Why is this gap in a circle - Custom Painter - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to draw a circle with 12 segments and with Random colors in Flutter. I am using CustomPainter with drawArc method.
I am check for the screen size first to ensure that the app is responsive in all phones. To this, I am get the screenheight and screenwidth as follows:

```
 if (screenheight - safearea > screenwidth / 2) {
      blockwidth = screenheight - safearea;
      blockheight = screenheight - safearea;
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      blockwidth = screenwidth / 2;
      blockheight = screenheight - safearea;
      setState(() {});
    }
```

Once I have the block sizes, I am calling the InnerRing passing the height and width from homepage. This is the InnerRing.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InnerRing extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  const InnerRing({Key? key, required this.width, required this.height})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: CustomPaint(
        painter: MaasaRing(width: width, height: height),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MaasaRing extends CustomPainter {
  final double width;
  final double height;

  MaasaRing({required this.width, required this.height});
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double offwidth = width / 4;
    double offheight = height / 4;
    double sizewidth = width / 2;
    double sizeheight = height / 2;

    Paint arc(int color) {
      final paint = Paint()
        ..color =
            Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0)
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = 18;
      return paint;
    }


    double stepup = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      canvas.drawArc(Offset(offwidth, offheight) & Size(sizewidth, sizeheight),
          stepup, 1 * pi / 6, false, arc(i));
      stepup = stepup + .5;
      print(stepup);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Question is why am I getting this gap in the circle. I am expecting to see 12 arcs complete the 360°. Check the image enclosed.
[image: Gap in Circle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you increment `stepup` by `0.5` on every iteration. That will result in `12 * 0.5` = `6.0` for the entire loop, but it should by `2 * pi` to fill the entire circle. The difference is what you see as an empty arc.

Change this:

```
stepup = stepup + .5;
```

to this:

```
stepup = stepup + pi / 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Peter's answer, there is one more point that could cause part of the circle becoming black. The way you initialize the color

```
..Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0)
```

might cause it to be entirely black, because [`nextDouble()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-math/Random/nextDouble.html) can return 0.

Comment: The solution @Peter Koltai gave solved the issue. Thanks for pointing this out. Yes, there is an issue with the black against the black background.